# Getting Links in Multiple Categories (intersection)

Tags: get-bookmarks

I am using [`get_bookmarks()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks) to get bookmark links. I can get links posted in cat A ***or*** cat B, but I only want links in both A ***and*** B.

**Example what I need:**

I have three link categories `cat#1`, `cat#2`, `cat#3`.

I need to get links in both `cat#1 AND cat#2` not `cat#1 OR cat#2` (intersection).

**I am currently using:**

```
$links = get_bookmarks(array('category' => $term_ids));
```

Which doesn't work because of [how `get_bookmarks()` works](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/bookmark.php#L194).

```
        $category_query = '';
        $join = '';
        if ( !empty($category) ) {
                $incategories = preg_split('/[\s,]+/',$category);
                if ( count($incategories) ) {
                        foreach ( $incategories as $incat ) {
                                if (empty($category_query))
                                        $category_query = ' AND ( tt.term_id = ' . intval($incat) . ' ';
                                else
                                        $category_query .= ' OR tt.term_id = ' . intval($incat) . ' ';
                        }
                }
        }
```

<sup>Note from the Editor: Adding sample code for easier understanding - Bookmarks get queried with an `OR` clause by default. As they're retrieved via `$wpdb->get_result()`, there's no easy solution in filtering aside from the queried result.</sup>

Any help or idea of different approach would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to make a new function out of get_bookmarks() function.

I changed the code that shown above to this below (changed OR to AND). But now nothing is returning. Perhaps i need to change the SQL to something else. So, I will need **advice on this.**

```
if ( !empty($category) ) {
        $incategories = preg_split('/[\s,]+/',$category);
        if ( count($incategories) ) {
            foreach ( $incategories as $incat ) {
                if (empty($category_query))
                    $category_query = ' AND ( tt.term_id = ' . intval($incat) . ' ';
                else{
                    // sisir
                    $category_query .= ' AND tt.term_id = ' . intval($incat) . ' ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as that: Just get the terms from the `link_category` and use the `get_terms()` argument instead, which should work like you need it.

```
get_terms(
     'link_category'
    ,array(
         'include'      => array( 1, 2, 3 )
        ,'orderby'      => 'name'
        ,'order'        => 'ASC'
        ,'hierarchical' => 0
     )
);
```

Comment: I already have those terms as term id. I need links as result. Not sure why you used `get_terms()`..

Comment: @Sisir [Take a look at the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/bookmark-template.php#L200).

Comment: i see what you mean but on the source they still use `get_bookmarks()` function in the end. So, i am not sure i understand :-/

Answer (score 1):

Forking `get_bookmarks()` seems troublesome, I'd code out a bit (and cache if it gets slow). Something like this:

```
/**
 * Retrieve links that have all of the terms assigned.
 * 
 * @param array $term_ids
 *
 * @return array of link objects
 */
function get_bookmarks_in_terms( $term_ids ) {

    $bookmark_ids = array();

    foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {

        $bookmarks_in_term = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, 'link_category' );

        if ( empty( $bookmarks_in_term ) )
            return array();

        if ( empty( $bookmark_ids ) )
            $bookmark_ids = $bookmarks_in_term;
        else
            $bookmark_ids = array_intersect( $bookmark_ids, $bookmarks_in_term );
    }

    if ( empty( $bookmark_ids ) )
        return array();

    return get_bookmarks( array( 'include' => implode( ',', $bookmark_ids ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_objects_in_term` to grab all objects using those terms so somethign similar to this:

```
$objects = get_objects_in_term($term_ids,'link_category');
$links = get_bookmarks(array('include' => $objects ));
```

Comment: Somebody downvoted this answer, could you explain why so I can fix it?

Comment: Wasn't me, but issues I see here - would fetch object in any term, not combination of terms and needs to be imploded into string in arguments.